# How to specify network interface with Ruby's Faraday?

Tags: ruby, networking, curb, faraday

I'm using [Faraday](https://github.com/technoweenie/faraday) which wraps various adapters, including Net::HTTP, Excon, Typhoeus, Patron, and EventMachine. I would like to specify the network interface (e.g. `en0` or `en1`), but I'm not sure how or if it is possible. I'd be open to answers at the Ruby level or the Linux level.

Note: According to [Making HTTP requests from different network interfaces with Ruby and Curb](http://blog.sosedoff.com/2010/06/09/making-http-requests-from-different-network-interfaces-with-ruby-and-curb/), this is possible with [Curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it even is possible to do that with Faraday and Typhoeus: https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus/blob/92d19df7af06034ae28996e097676b01301042f5/lib/typhoeus/adapters/faraday.rb#L139.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is possible to bind to specific network interface, but with Faraday you can set request option `:bind` to `{:host => "<your_ip>", :port => "<your_port>" }` to specify at least IP address and port.

As far as I know em-http, em-synchrony, httpclient & typhoeus adapters respect these settings.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue with Typhoeus (not using Faraday) and binding to a specific local interface. The following worked for me:

```
options = {
  interface: '<ip address>'
}
req = Typhoeus::Request.new("https://example.com/3", options)
```