# Making Faraday HTTP requests from multiple IPs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

I am trying to do something like this to have different request come from different IP's at random.

```
   random_ip = ["127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.2"].sample    

    conn = Faraday.new(:url => url) do |faraday|
         faraday.request  :url_encoded             # form-encode POST params
         faraday.response :logger                  # log requests to STDOUT
         faraday.adapter  Faraday.default_adapter  # make requests with Net::HTTP
         faraday.host random_ip
    end
    result = conn.get url
```

IP's are on a Linux dedicated server if it makes any difference.

Comment: What does this code do? What's the problem?

Comment: It is supposed to randomly select from an array and use the ip selected as the IP making the request, but I cannot figure out how to do it in Rails. faraday.host is not a real option it's just an example.

Comment: I think `host` specifies the host to connect *to*. Might want to check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854660/how-to-specify-network-interface-with-rubys-faraday).